# Altering Linux with Buildroot

Tags: ubuntu, buildroot

Could you please tell me how can I use Buildroot on the image of Ubuntu, remove some of its parts such as graphics, and save the image file of a lighter Ubuntu?

Comment: better question for http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Buildroot. Buildroot builds a system from scratch, it is not meant to alter an existing system.

You may want to start out with reading the [Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/manual) if you want to understand what Buildroot does.